# Chrome blocks my extensions html file when opening it through javascript [FIXED, i was just dumb]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing a chrome extension. I have a button that should open the settings.html file in my extensions root directory. But it gets blocked by chrome saying "requests to the server have been blocked by an extension" and "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT". I have tested it, and no addon blocks it. But if I open it by creating a new tab and pasting the link in, it works and shows the html file.
Heres my code:

```
function gotosettings_first() {
    console.log("TO THE SETTINGS!!!");
    var settings_url = chrome.runtime.getURL("settings.html");
    //console.log(settings_url);
    //window.location.href = settings_url;
    var sw = window.open(settings_url, "_blank");
    sw.focus();
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: If this is in the background script or in the popup script then use chrome.windows.create({url: 'settings.html'}).

Comment: Thanks for answering @wOxxOm !
I tried it, but I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.gotosettings_first". So I think its not in the background or popup script? Is there a way to do it in a normal script?

Comment: If this is a script declared in `content_scripts` or injected via chrome.tabs.executeScript then you will need to expose settings.html in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and reload the extension + tabs.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with developing chrome extensions, so I dont know if I really did everything right in my manifest.json. But I have my script in content_scripts and my settings.html file is exposed:

"permissions": ["tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [{
      "js": [
        "app.js"
      ],
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        "settings.html"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://domain.de/*",
        "https://second_domain.de/*"
      ]


Also, im sorry for asnwering so late. I didn't expect you to answer that fast :D

Comment: If you followed my suggestions then it should work.

Comment: So... I had "web_accesible" after "content_scripts". That was why it didnt work. Im sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for helping me